# RewriteRule appends subfolder to url when redirecting to rtmp protocol

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rtmp

I'm using htaccess to redirect to a rtmp stream

```
RewriteRule ^redirect$ rtmp://url.tv/live/
```

The htaccess is located at `/subfolder1/subfolder2/`

The problem is that this path is prepended to the rtmp url

I get this error:

`The requested URL /subfolder1/subfolder2/rtmp://url.tv/live/ was not found on this server.`

With a `http` url, this works fine.
I also tried using the `DPI` flag but with no luck

```
RewriteRule ^redirect$ rtmp://url.tv/live/ [DPI]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace that rule with this `RedirectMatch` rule:

```
RedirectMatch ^/redirect/?$ rtmp://url.tv/live/
```

Otherwise `RewriteRule` doesn't recognize `rtmp://` as an independent protocol and appends `http://` to target URI if using `R` flag.

Comment: It works for me but I need to hide the rtmp url! This redirection is visible

Comment: @Samurai8 Please post the `Protocol` directive bit, maybe it helps

Comment: I don't think you can do `http->rtmp` silent rewrite.

Comment: Yes you are right. I checked the mod source and its function `is_absolute_url` doesn't test for rtmp. I thought it would test for `://` but it tests for specific protocols!

Comment: Yes that's right, only with external redirect it works as I suggested.